# Multiple PDU Types Possible in SNMP Packet?

Tags: udp, snmp, asn.1

I have been using SNMP for a couple of months now but am still relatively new to the intricacies of the specification.

Is it possible to put multiple types of PDU's in an SNMPv1/v2/v3 packet? For example, can I put a GetRequest and a SetRequest in the same packet. If so, is there defined behavior on how an Agent should respond if the same value was set and get in the same packet? If not, would the wrongEncoding error be used by an Agent to signal this problem?

Comment: No. The language in the RFCs is 'every message being
   entirely and independently contained in a single transport datagram,' and a message consists of exactly one PDU.